# How can I do a strict check on if a Ruby array contains only certain values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to check an Array and see if it contains only certain values of another Array.

I can think of ways to do this using the methods `map` and `select` and then iterating through the array with `includes?` but this would be far from efficient.

```rb
values = ['2','4','5'] # return true if the array only contains these values...

a = ['1', '2', '3']
b = ['1', '2', '4']
c = ['2', '4']
d = ['4', '5']

def compare(checked_array, standard)
 # Do something
end
```

So, for my purpose, output should be,

- check(a, values) would return false
- check(b, values) would return false
- check(c, values) would return true
- check(d, values) would return true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple subtraction will provide you desired output,

```
def compare(checked_array, standard)
 (checked_array - standard).empty?
end
```

Comment: This is simple and efficient, thanks!
Its one line of code where I would have used 15... much better 

Answer (score 4):

Another way with arrays intersection:

```
def compare(checked_array, standard)
  (checked_array & standard) == standard
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably not as short and sweet as using subtraction/intersection but here goes:

```
require "set"
def compare(check_array, standard
    standard.to_set.superset?(check_array.to_set) # return true if check_array is subset of standard
end
```

Comment: There is no method as superset, its superset? `standard.to_set.superset?(check_array.to_set)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Set#subset?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-subset-3F):

```
require 'set'

def compare(checked_array, standard)
 s = Set.new(standard)
 c = Set.new(checked_array)
 c.subset? s
end
```

As the documentation states:

> Set implements a collection of unordered values with **no duplicates**. This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation facilities and Hash's **fast lookup**.